# Time complexity of a recursive function with two variables

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

I have a recursive function that takes two variables and then splits in two calls:

```py
def f(n, m):
    if ((n == 0) or (m == 0)):
        return 1

    return f(n - 1, m) + f(n, m - 1)
```

The first three recursive calls look like this:

```
                    f(n-2, m)
                   /
          f(n-1, m)
         /         \
        /           f(n-1, m-1)
       /
f(n, m)
       \
        \           f(n-1, m-1)
         \         /
          f(n, m-1)
                   \
                    f(n, m-2)
```

I know that a function which splits in two calls will have an exponential time complexity of `O(2^n)`, but how can I also include the second argument and its condition?

Comment: What you pass to each function isn't going to change the time complexity.

Comment: check on Wikipedia `Master Theorem` https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_principale

Comment: @RobertHarvey What would be the time complexity for this function with two arguments?

Comment: You already stated that the time complexity for this function is `O(2^n)`, and why.  I stated that the number of arguments isn't going to matter (unless, of course, you add more function splits).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you please elaborate on this? If this function is called with `m=0` it will always execute in `O(1)` regardless of `n` so `O(2^n)` might not be accurate for every case.

Comment: Big O is supposed to be worst-case, not best-case.  Or at the very least, common case.  If you put items into a binary tree in alphabetical order, its performance is going to be O(n), not O(log2 n).  But nobody says that insertion performance in a binary tree is O(n), because that's not the common case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! Please submit an answer so this can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass to each function isn't going to change the time complexity.

Big O is supposed to be worst-case, not best-case. Or at the very least, common case. If you put items into a binary tree in alphabetical order, its performance is going to be O(n), not O(log2 n). But nobody says that insertion performance in a binary tree is O(n), because that's not the common case.

Comment: Shouldn't the time complexity be at least in terms of n and m? for example O(2^Max(n,m)) or O(2^(n+m)? It's strange to me that the time complexity for that function is only in terms of n.

Answer (score 1):

take the `function(n,m)`,
plug in n=1, m=2, count the recursive calls.
It is not max(m,n) nor n*m, the maximum depth is n+m or `O(2^(n+m))` to get to n=0,m=0.